# How edge rails work when rails gem does not dynamically link to other gems like active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I create a brand new rails application then the Gemfile says.

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

Now lets go and look at rails project on github. At https://github.com/rails/rails there are two files of our interest.

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec

The second file declares dependency on activerecord by version. and the current version is '4.0.0.beta'. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/RAILS_VERSION

If means periodically rails core guys will push beta version and I will get beta version. However I might or might NOT get the edge ( latest master on github ) of activerecord.

Now lets look at rspec-expectations Gemfile. 
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Gemfile#L10 . Here it links to github repo so I am guaranteed to get latest github stuff.

So does that mean that rails edge is kind of sort of edge but not really really edge !

Answer (score 0):

When you run on edge bundler will download the Rails github repo and all gems, including `active_record`, are also going to be in there, as they are **inside** the rails repo. So, yes, you will have the latest version of everything that's in there.

Comment: Just because they are inside it will not work. It has to be referenced and I am looking for that reference.